# Syncing audio/video in pyav decoding

Tags: python, playback, pyaudio, video-player, pyav

I am making a simple video player with pyav, and using the `container.decode(video=0, audio=0)` method to decode both audio and video frames, then syncing them using PIL and pyaudio.

Here is the summary code/method I used:

```py
import av
import pyaudio
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

...
                                    
with av.open(path, "r") as self._container:

    audio_stream = self._container.streams.audio[0]
              
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    audio_stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, 
                          channels=audio_stream.channels, 
                          rate=audio_stream.rate, output=True)
    

    while True:
        try:
            frame = next(self._container.decode(video=0, audio=0)) # decode both audio and video simultaneously
            
            if 'Video' in repr(frame):
                # show the video frame
                self._current_img = frame.to_image() # converts the video frame to pil image  
                self._current_imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self._current_img) 
                self.label.config(image=self._current_imgtk) # display the image in a tk label

            else:
                # play the audio frame
                audio_data = frame.to_ndarray().astype('float32')
                interleaved_data = audio_data.T.flatten().tobytes()
                audio_stream.write(interleaved_data)
                
        except (StopIteration, av.error.EOFError, tk.TclError):
                break
    
    self._container = None
    audio_stream.stop_stream()
    audio_stream.close()
    p.terminate()

...
```

The video/audio is properly synced when decoding is done like this (according to pts):

```
video_frame

audio_frame 
audio_frame

video_frame

audio_frame 
audio_frame
...
```

But not all videos are decoded like this, instead a continues series is decoded and not synced properly:

```
video_frame
video_frame
video_frame
video_frame

audio_frame
audio_frame
audio_frame
audio_frame
audio_frame
audio_frame

video_frame
video_frame
video_frame
video_frame
...
```

it just stutters between audio and video frames

**Is there any method to decode both frames evenly for all videos?**
Or at least provide any similar project of video player using pyav like this.

I am actually working on this project: https://github.com/Akascape/tkVideoPlayer

Thank you

Comment: yeah it's your job to play each frame (audio or video) when it is ***due***, i.e. at its presentation timestamp (PTS). practically, you are supposed to continually feed the audio into an audio playback thingy (without delay). you'll assume that the audio playback keeps to real time, if you told it the right sample rate. then you'll take that audio playback clock to be your clock for the entire playback, and display frames according to this clock and their PTSes.

Comment: I did specifically *not add* the [tag:tkinter] tag because those kinds of people are highly likely to have opinions on this without knowing how audio+video players work.

Comment: the audio playback will have some buffer that holds some audio. you are *not* supposed to time your images according to what you put *into* that buffer. you are supposed to time your image display according to when the audio playback *plays* each audio frame, or some other mechanism that derives from this audio clock. let's say the audio comes in frames of 50 ms (20 fps) but your video is 25 fps. that's why. just going by "this audio frame is playing now" would *not* let you track time properly. the clock needs to have some mechanism to *call you back* at the *video* frame rate (or next PTS)

Comment: yes, all of this necessarily involves buffering the audio and video frames that you decode, until they're *due to be presented* (PTS). you can't rely on the media container ordering those things in their presentation order. with some video formats, they're guaranteed *not* to be in presentation order, but in decode order ("adjacent fence posts first, then panel between both", called B-frames). some video libraries *may* have ways to reorder that stuff for you but even then you have to get the presentation timing right. you can't just present the frames as soon as you're given them.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz So for now is there any way to re-encode the video (reordering the frames) so that the decode order becomes the presentation order, maybe changing the codec like mentioned here: https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/1023

Comment: when you find random people saying stuff in an issue, assume that none of them have any idea what they're saying. -- reencoding? BAD idea. terrible. will fix nothing and only make things worse. just implement buffering as I described it. nothing to it.